# AMFPHP / ZENDAMF optimization

Tags: php, optimization, browser-cache, amfphp, zend-amf

Is there a way to cache AMFPHP / ZENDAMF requests. I have used several chaching solutions like Cache_Lite and memCached in the past, but never for AMFPHP / ZENDAMF. Does anyone know any?

Comment: You should note that AMFPHP will not have ready built viable solutions for catching. Also, the slowest component of AMFPHP is the call to gateway.php which will be executed even if you use catching. ZENDAMF as a framework will be able to reuse catching practices commonly known in Zend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well Zend_Cache handles an all binary input & output, but [Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html) or maybe the Zend_Cache_Frontend_Output appear to be the best matches. They will take the URL, GET & POST variables, and if all match to a previously generated cache, output that. If there is no cache with that input data, they will cache the generated output for next time.